# Nested procedure rollback in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Following is the code for outer and nested procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.NestedProcedure
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @trancount INT
        SET @trancount = @@TRANCOUNT
        IF @trancount = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ELSE 
            SAVE TRANSACTION NestedProcedure

            ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_2
            ALTER COLUMN Column3 VARCHAR
        IF @trancount = 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT XACT_STATE()
        DECLARE @error INT, @message VARCHAR(4000), @xstate INT;
        SELECT @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        IF XACT_STATE() = -1
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
        END
        IF XACT_STATE() = 1 AND @trancount = 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
        END
        IF XACT_STATE() = 1 AND @trancount > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION NestedProcedure
        END
        RAISERROR ('NestedProcedure: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message)
    END CATCH
END

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.OuterProcedure
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @trancount INT
        SET @trancount = @@TRANCOUNT
        IF @trancount = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ELSE 
            SAVE TRANSACTION OuterProcedure
            EXEC dbo.NestedProcedure
            SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_2
        IF @trancount = 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT XACT_STATE()
        DECLARE @error INT, @message VARCHAR(4000), @xstate INT;
        SELECT @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        IF XACT_STATE() = -1
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
        END
        IF XACT_STATE() = 1 AND @trancount = 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
        END
        IF XACT_STATE() = 1 AND @trancount > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION OuterProcedure
        END
        RAISERROR ('OuterProcedure: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message)
    END CATCH
END
```

I am calling the OuterProcedure like

```
EXEC dbo.OuterProcedure
```

and I get an error like

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure OuterProcedure, Line 34
>   OuterProcedure: 50000: NestedProcedure: 4922: ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Column3 failed because one or more objects access this column

`XACT_STATE()` being -1 for the nested procedure is fine because the error is understandable but why is the `XACT_STATE()` becoming -1 even for the outer procedure? I only intend to roll back the nested procedure till the savepoint no matter if it is a runtime error. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

XACT_STATE() being -1 indicates that the transaction is uncommitable. No more writes of any kind can commit within a transaction once it enters this doomed state. There are certain classes of errors that would cause a transaction to get into this state. Unfortunately, it is difficult to clearly delineate what kinds of errors cause these. Look at this article for an good deep dive.

http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification

Also, see the description on the TRY..CATCH and XACT_STATE documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql#uncommittable-transactions-and-xactstate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql

You might need to consider higher level work-around if you really need your outer procedure to do some work despite inner procedure dooming the transaction. One approach is to retry the outer procedure with a flag to avoid repeating the trasaction-dooming error once a first attempt results in such an error.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the links.